# How to Add multiple choice checkboxes in alert Dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have created menu "Sync" in android app. when we click on "Sync" alert open a 4 checkboxes layout. what I want is to have them in function like when I click on 15 minutes then other option unclicked automatically.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
    return true;
}       
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomePage.this).create(); //Read Update
            LayoutInflater adbInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View checkboxLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_layout, null);
            defaultchkbox = (CheckBox)checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.defaultchkbox);
            after15mint = (CheckBox)checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.after15mint);
            after30mint = (CheckBox)checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.after30mint);
            after45mint = (CheckBox)checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.after45mint);
            alertDialog.setView(checkboxLayout);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Synchronization");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Choose");

            alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Save changes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    boolean checkBoxResult = false; 
                        if(after15mint.isChecked())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "15 Minute checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            checkBoxResult = true;
                        }
                        else if(after30mint.isChecked())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "30 Minute checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            checkBoxResult = true;
                        }
                        else if(after45mint.isChecked())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "45 Minute checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            checkBoxResult = true;
                        }   
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),     "Default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show(); 
            return true;
default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But I am little bit confused over working of check boxes in alert. Suggestions will be great help. Thank you. :)[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to work with Radio Buttons which are nested within a RadioGroup. It will then only allow you to select one option at a time.

For more information on RadioGroup look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

For more information on creating Radio Buttons look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html

in particular to your code you will have to define RadioButtons within a RadioGroup in your R.layout.sync_layout like for example

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/syncGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/defualt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "Default" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/minute15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "15 Minute" />


     <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/minute30"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text= "30 Minute" />


      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/minute45"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text= "45 Minute" />



</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: i need to implement with checkboxes only

Comment: any particular reason why? You will save on the code that you will have to right for doing all the manual work for checking and unchecking the tick boxes and might be prone to errors/bugs even if you achieve that. Radio Buttons is a concrete API provided by the Android Framework to achieve such a purpose

Comment: okay, thank you. let me try with radio buttons. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) link.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color);
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```